# Adding background to annotated text on image in Imagick

Tags: php, image, imagick, caption, annotate

everyone. I am doing a college project on Online Photo Editor but I am facing some problem in adding a background color to the text that I'm adding on an image using Imagick. Below is the php code for Imagick used

caption.php

```
<?php
$caption =  $_POST['caption'];
$caption_color =  $_POST['caption_color'];
$caption_color =  "#".$caption_color;
$font =  $_POST['font'];

$image = new Imagick();
$draw = new ImagickDraw();
$data = "\intermediate.jpg";
$im = new Imagick(__DIR__.$data);
$im->setImageFormat("jpg");

$draw->setFillColor($caption_color);
$draw->setFont('Arial');
$draw->setFontSize( $font );

$im->annotateImage($draw, $im->getImageWidth()/2, $im->getImageHeight()/2, 0, $caption);

header('Content-type: image/jpg');
$im->writeImages(__DIR__.$data, true);
```

?>

This is the result I'm getting
[Link to Resulted Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jBd1.png)

This is what I want
[Link to Desired Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wqAs.jpg)

How can I achieve that desired result. Any help is very much appreciated.
Just in case needed, below is the ajax request and html that is sending the values

effect.php

```
function myCaptionAjax() {
var loader = $("#ajax-loader");
var div_loader = $("#img");
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'effects/caption.php',
            data: {caption: $('#caption_value').val(),caption_color: $('#caption_color').val(),font: $('#font_value').val()},
            beforeSend: function () {
            loader.show();
            div_loader.hide();
        },
        success: function ( data ) {
        loader.hide();
        div_loader.show();
        display();
        },
        error: function ( xhr ) {
        alert( "error" );
    }
        });
};
```

html part residing within effect.php

```
Caption:<input type="textarea" rows="4" cols="10" maxlength="40" id="caption_value" />&nbsp;
    <input id="caption_color" class="jscolor" value="ab2567">
    <input type="range" min="10" max="50" value="10" step="1" onchange="showFont(this.value)" id="font_value"/>&nbsp;<span id="rangeFont"></span>
    <button class="button" onclick="myCaptionAjax()">Apply</button>
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use annotateImage.

Instead draw the text in ImagickDraw object, and then composite that over an image using Imagick::drawImage like in this example: http://phpimagick.com/Imagick/drawImage

Comment: I solved the problem myself , though thanks for the suggestion. I will keep that drawImage () function in mind for later use.